# Read and represent mp3 files using memmapfile in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, machine-learning, mp3, large-files

I have to analyze bio acoustic audiofiles using matlab. Eventually I want to be able to find anomalies in the audio. That's the reason I need to find a way to represent the audio in a way I can extract and compare features.  I'm dealing with mp3 files up to 150 mb. These files are too large for matlab to read in to it's memory. Therefore I want to use the memmapfile() function. I used the following code and a small mp3 file to find out how it actually works.

```
[testR, ~] = audioread('test.mp3');
testM = memmapfile('test.mp3');
disp(testM.Data);
disp(testR);
```

The actual values of the testM.Data and testR are different. Audioread() returns a 7483391 x 2 matrix and memmapfile() a 4113874 x 1 matrix.
I'm not really sure how memmapfile() works, I expected this to be equal to each other. Is there a way to read mp3 files in the same format audioread() does using memmapfile()? And what does memmapfile actually return in case of an audio file? Maybe it's also usable in the vector format in the case of anomaly detection?

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: The original files were in wav IMA ADPCM format with sizes from 1.5 up to 2.5 gb. Since Matlab can't deal with that format and the size of the files I converted them to 8bit mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is mammapfile by default read data in uint8 format, while audioread function read data in another way.
How you can see [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) you can specify the format of data when you read it with memmapfile, so try to "play" with different values. From the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) I read that you can read data in double format, so try to modify the memmapfile data format and audioread data format.
Last thing, memmapfile always organize the data in matrix like "somenumbers x 1", so if you want the original one you need to use something like reshape.
Anyway if you work with big data I suggest you to try with something different instead memmapfile, because it is very very slow

Comment: You are right, memmapfile is not the right solution. I decided to read the files in chunks. This works perfectly!